# Flutter HTTP POST Request with TextField Controller

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make http post request with 2 var as my parameter. If I type the first and second var (into my textfield) and then I click Submit, it will do http request. It works, but I'm trying to re-format/parse the response into List.

```
Future<Repair> getRepair(String Id, String title) async {
  final String apiUrl =
      "*****";

  final response =
      await http.post(apiUrl, body: {"id": Id, "title": title});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final String responseString = response.body;

    return repairModelFromJson(responseString);

  } else {
    print(null);
    return null;
  }
}

class _MainFetchDataState extends State<MainFetchData> {
  Repair _repair;

  final TextEditingController caseController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController serialController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Fecth"),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Submit"),
          onPressed: () async {
            final String Id = idController.text;
            final String title = titleController.text;

            final Repair repair = await getRepair(Id, title);

            setState(() {
              _repair = repair;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: idController,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: titleController,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 32,
          ),
          _repair == null
              ? Container()
              : Text(_repair.movement.toString() != null ? "${_repair.movement.toString()}" : 'Vuoto'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and

```
import 'dart:convert';

Repair repairModelFromJson(String str) => Repair.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String repairModelToJson(Repair data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Repair {
  String Id;
  String title;
  String movement;

  Repair({
    this.Id,
    this.title,
    this.movement,
  });

  factory Repair.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Repair(
    Id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    movement: json['movement'].toString(),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": Id,
    "title": title,
    "movement": movement,
  };
}
```

Now, I show this (image) and i would like to show the response like a List.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCtyu.png)

Comment: Hey leon you should use list view builder for this